# How do I use a member of a struct array as the first argument for fread()?

Tags: c

I get

> passing argument 1 of 'fread' makes pointer from integer without a cast

when I do

```
fread((*pArr)[i][j]->b, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
```

in my `readPixelsBMP` function. And

```
fread(&(*pArr)[i][j]->b, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
```

makes it crash but gives no warnings. My program is just a program that is supposed to read an image and write that same image. Here is my whole code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
struct BMP_Header {
    char signature[2];
    int size;
    short reserved1;
    short reserved2;
    int offset_pixel_array;
};
    
struct DIB_Header{
    int  size;
    int width;
    int height;
    short planes;
    short bits_per_pixel;
    int compression;
    int image_size;
    int x_per_meter;
    int y_per_meter;
    int colors_in_table;
    int important_colors;
};
    
struct Pixel{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char g;
};
void readBMPHeader(FILE* file, struct BMP_Header* header) {
    fread(&header->signature, sizeof(char) *2, 1,file);
    fread(&header->size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fread(&header->reserved1, sizeof(short), 1,file);
    fread(&header->reserved2, sizeof(short), 1,file);
    fread(&header->offset_pixel_array, sizeof(int), 1,file);
}
void readDIBHeader(FILE* file, struct DIB_Header* header) {
    fread(&header->size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fread(&header->width, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fread(&header->height, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fread(&header->planes, sizeof(short), 1,file);
    fread(&header->bits_per_pixel, sizeof(short), 1,file);
    fread(&header->compression, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fread(&header->image_size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fread(&header->x_per_meter, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fread(&header->y_per_meter, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fread(&header->colors_in_table, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fread(&header->important_colors, sizeof(int), 1,file);
}
void readPixelsBMP(FILE* file, int width, int height, struct Pixel (**pArr)[width][height]) {
    *pArr = malloc( sizeof(struct Pixel[width][height]) );
    if (*pArr == NULL) {
        printf("Error! Insufficient memory!");
        return;
    }
    
    int padding = (4 - ((3*width) % 4)) % 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            //fread(*pArr, sizeof(struct Pixel), 1, file);
            fread(&(*pArr)[i][j]->b, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
            //fread((*pArr)[i][j]->r, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
            //fread((*pArr)[i][j]->g, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
        }
        if (padding) {
            fseek(file, padding, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
void writeBMPHeader(FILE* file, struct BMP_Header* header) {
    fwrite(&header->signature, sizeof(char) *2, 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->reserved1, sizeof(short), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->reserved2, sizeof(short), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->offset_pixel_array, sizeof(int), 1,file);
}
void writeDIBHeader(FILE* file, struct DIB_Header* header) {
    fwrite(&header->size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->width, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->height, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->planes, sizeof(short), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->bits_per_pixel, sizeof(short), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->compression, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->image_size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->x_per_meter, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->y_per_meter, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->colors_in_table, sizeof(int), 1,file);
    fwrite(&header->important_colors, sizeof(int), 1,file);
}
void writePixelsBMP(FILE* file, int width, int height, struct Pixel (**pArr)[width][height]) {
    int padding = (4 - ((3*width) % 4)) % 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            fwrite(*pArr, sizeof(struct Pixel), 1, file);
        }
        if (padding)
            fwrite("0", sizeof(char),padding, file);
    }
    char eof = 0x00;
    fwrite(&eof, sizeof(char), 1, file);
}
    
int main() {
    char* filename = "test1wonderbread.bmp";
    char* output = "test3wonderbread.bmp";
    FILE* file_input = fopen(filename, "rb");
    FILE* file_output = fopen(output, "wb");
    
    struct BMP_Header* header = (struct BMP_Header*) malloc(sizeof(struct BMP_Header));
    readBMPHeader(file_input, header);
    struct DIB_Header* dib_header = (struct DIB_Header*) malloc(sizeof(struct DIB_Header));
    readDIBHeader(file_input, dib_header);
    
    struct Pixel (*pArr)[dib_header->width][dib_header->height];
    readPixelsBMP(file_input, dib_header->width, dib_header->height, &pArr);
    
    writeBMPHeader(file_output, header);
    writeDIBHeader(file_output, dib_header);
    //writePixelsBMP(file_output, dib_header->width, dib_header->height, &pArr);
    printf("no errors");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"makes it crash but gives no warnings"*. But the **compiler** did warn you, so what do you expect? C has no "about to crash" system, it is a raw low level language.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think he means the second version had no compiler warnings but crashed.

Comment: Every time I see this code it makes less sense. Why not just allocate the array for the pixels outside the function like you do for the headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have so many levels of indirection ....

`(*pArr)[i][j]` is pointer to 1 dimension array to struct pixel.

You can access the whole struct

```
(*(*pArr))[i][j] 
(**pArr)[i][j] 
(*pArr)[0][i][j]
pArr[0][0][i][j]
```

and in your `fread`:

```
    fread(&(*(*pArr))[i][i], sizeof((*(*pArr))[i][i]), 1, file);
    fread(&(**pArr)[i][j],   sizeof((**pArr)[i][j]),   1, file);
    fread(&(*pArr)[0][i][i], sizeof((*pArr)[0][i][i]), 1, file);
    fread(&pArr[0][0][i][i], sizeof(pArr[0][0][i][i]), 1, file);
```

or accessing particular members

```
    fread(&(*(*pArr))[i][i].r, sizeof((*(*pArr))[i][i].r), 1, file);
    fread(&(**pArr)[i][j].r,   sizeof((**pArr)[i][j].r),   1, file);
    fread(&(*pArr)[0][i][i].r, sizeof((*pArr)[0][i][i].r), 1, file);
    fread(&pArr[0][0][i][i].r, sizeof(pArr[0][0][i][i].r), 1, file);
```

Use objects not types in `sizeof`. Compiler will automatically change it if you for example change members to another type.

Answer (score 1):

The code as posted is very very complex, may be with no reason.

5 + 11 calls to `fread` to just get the bitmap headers? 5 + 11 calls to `fwrite` to write the same headers? Why is it so?

**All this for 54 bytes?**.

And not counting the calls to read the actual pixels...

I will show here a way to read and write bitmaps, with code and some arguments. The basic difference here is the encapsulation of the bitmap

**Once more I will left a long post because I think it can be useful to have a complete code to read, draw and write bitmaps in `C` here.**

Fell free to ignore.

#### A bitmap `struct` and a few methods

```
typedef struct
{
    char    header[2];
    int32_t fileSize;
    int32_t reserved;
    int32_t dataOffset;
} BitmapFileHeader;

typedef struct
{
    int32_t headerSize;
    int32_t width;
    int32_t height;
    int16_t planes;
    int16_t bitsPerPixel;
    int32_t compression;
    int32_t dataSize;
    int32_t horizontalResolution;
    int32_t verticalResolution;
    int32_t colors;
    int32_t importantColors;
} BitmapInfoHeader;

typedef struct
{
    BitmapFileHeader h_bmp;
    BitmapInfoHeader h_info;
    uint8_t*         pixel;
} Bitmap;

    Bitmap* bmp_create(unsigned w, unsigned h);
    Bitmap* bmp_destroy(Bitmap* bmp);
    int     bmp_fill(Bitmap*, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t);
    int     bmp_grad(Bitmap* bmp);
    Bitmap* bmp_read(const char* filename);
    int     bmp_setPixel(
            Bitmap* bmp, int x, int y, uint8_t red, uint8_t green,
            uint8_t blue);
    int bmp_write(Bitmap* bmp, const char* filename);
```

`bmp_grad` builds a thing like [image] on any bitmap drawing area.
The other functions does what is expected, considering their names. A simple (complete) implementation is here at the end of the post. Code for a test and also the output follows.

#### `main()` for a test

The code below shows the functions in use. The program:

- creates a 1024x768 bmp
- fills the bitmap in red, green and blue and saves 3 bitmaps to disk. This is the code for the 1st one, `red.bmp`:

```
    res = bmp_fill(a_test, 255, 0, 0);  // red
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_fill returned %d\n", res);
    res = bmp_write(a_test, "red.bmp");
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_write() returned %d\n", res);
```

- one of the bitmaps is read from disk using `bmp_read` and then saved as a copy in `blueCopy.bmp`

```
    Bitmap* a_copy = bmp_read("blue.bmp");
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_read() read a [%d x %d], size is %d\n", 
        a_copy->h_info.width,
        a_copy->h_info.height,
        a_copy->h_bmp.fileSize);
    res = bmp_write(a_copy, "blueCopy.bmp");
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_write() returned %d\n", res);
```

- the output of this:

```
        bmp_read() read a [1024 x 768], size is 3145782
        bmp_write() returned 0
```

- `bmp_grad` is called to paint the stripes and save a new bitmap as `stripes.bmp`.
- `bmp_setPixel` is used to draw a black 11-pixels-high line at the center of `stripes.bmp` and the bitmap is then saved as `lineset_Pixel.bmp` for something like this

[image]

#### `main.c` code

```
#include "bitmap.h"
int main(void)
{ 
    Bitmap* a_test = bmp_create(1024, 768);
    if (a_test == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\tbitmap not created\n");
        return -1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbitmap created ok!\n");
    int res = 0;

    res = bmp_fill(a_test, 255, 0, 0);  // red
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_fill returned %d\n", res);
    res = bmp_write(a_test, "red.bmp");
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_write() returned %d\n", res);

    res = bmp_fill(a_test, 0, 255, 0);  // green
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_fill() returned %d\n", res);
    res = bmp_write(a_test, "green.bmp");
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_write() returned %d\n", res);

    res = bmp_fill(a_test, 0, 0, 255);  // blue
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_fill() returned %d\n", res);
    res = bmp_write(a_test, "blue.bmp");
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_write() returned %d\n", res);

    Bitmap* a_copy = bmp_read("blue.bmp");
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_read() read a [%d x %d], size is %d\n", 
        a_copy->h_info.width,
        a_copy->h_info.height,
        a_copy->h_bmp.fileSize);
    res = bmp_write(a_copy, "blueCopy.bmp");
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_write() returned %d\n", res);
    
    res = bmp_grad(a_copy);
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_grad() returned %d\n", res);
    res = bmp_write(a_copy, "stripes.bmp");
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_write() returned %d\n", res);

    // draw a black line at the center of the bitmap
    for (int i = 0; i < a_copy->h_info.width; i += 1)
        for (int j = (a_copy->h_info.height / 2) - 5;
                 j < (a_copy->h_info.height / 2) + 5; j+=1)
        bmp_setPixel(a_copy, i, j, 0, 0, 0);
    res = bmp_write(a_copy, "lineset_Pixel.bmp");
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_write() returned %d\n", res);

    a_test = bmp_destroy(a_test);
    a_copy = bmp_destroy(a_copy);
    fprintf(stderr, "\t[end of tests]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### the `Bitmap.h` header

```
#pragma once
#pragma pack(push, 2)
#pragma pack(show)

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char    header[2];
    int32_t fileSize;
    int32_t reserved;
    int32_t dataOffset;
} BitmapFileHeader;

typedef struct
{
    int32_t headerSize;
    int32_t width;
    int32_t height;
    int16_t planes;
    int16_t bitsPerPixel;
    int32_t compression;
    int32_t dataSize;
    int32_t horizontalResolution;
    int32_t verticalResolution;
    int32_t colors;
    int32_t importantColors;
} BitmapInfoHeader;

typedef struct
{
    BitmapFileHeader h_bmp;
    BitmapInfoHeader h_info;
    uint8_t*         pixel;
} Bitmap;

    Bitmap* bmp_create(unsigned w, unsigned h);
    Bitmap* bmp_destroy(Bitmap* bmp);
    int     bmp_fill(Bitmap*, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t);
    int     bmp_grad(Bitmap* bmp);
    Bitmap* bmp_read(const char* filename);
    int     bmp_setPixel(
            Bitmap* bmp, int x, int y, uint8_t red, uint8_t green,
            uint8_t blue);
    int bmp_write(Bitmap* bmp, const char* filename);

#pragma pack(pop)
```

#### a possible `bitmap.c` complete implementation

```
#pragma pack(push, 2)
#pragma pack(show)
#include "bitmap.h"

Bitmap* bmp_create(unsigned w, unsigned h)
{
    Bitmap* one = (Bitmap*)calloc(1, sizeof(Bitmap));

    one->h_bmp.dataOffset =
        sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) + sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader);
    one->h_bmp.fileSize =
        one->h_bmp.dataOffset + (w * h * 4);
    // fprintf(
    //     stderr, "\tbmp_create(): file size is %u\n",
    //     one->h_bmp.fileSize);
    one->h_bmp.header[0] = 'B';
    one->h_bmp.header[1] = 'M';

    one->h_info.bitsPerPixel         = 32;
    one->h_info.headerSize           = 40;
    one->h_info.height               = h;
    one->h_info.horizontalResolution = 2400;
    one->h_info.planes               = 1;
    one->h_info.verticalResolution   = 2400;
    one->h_info.width                = w;
    one->pixel                       = (uint8_t*)calloc(
        1, (size_t)(w * h * 4 * sizeof(uint8_t)));
    if (one->pixel == NULL) return NULL;
    return one;
};

Bitmap* bmp_destroy(Bitmap* bmp)
{
    if (bmp == NULL) return NULL;
    if (bmp->pixel != NULL) free(bmp->pixel);
    free(bmp);
    fprintf(stderr, "\tbitmap destroyed\n");
    return NULL;
}

int bmp_fill(
    Bitmap* bmp, uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue)
{
    if (bmp == NULL) return -1;
    uint8_t* p = bmp->pixel;
    for (int32_t i = 0;
         i < bmp->h_info.width * bmp->h_info.height; i += 1)
    {  // 32bpp
        *p++ = blue;
        *p++ = green;
        *p++ = red;
        *p++ = 0xFF;  // alpha
    }
    return 0;
}

int bmp_grad(Bitmap* bmp)
{
    // fill screen with 3 vertical stripes R G B
    // color ranging from 0 to 255 in each line
    if (bmp == NULL) return -1;
    uint8_t  red   = 0;
    uint8_t  green = 0;
    uint8_t  blue  = 0;
    uint8_t* p     = bmp->pixel;
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp->h_info.height; y++)
    {
        uint8_t color_value =
            (uint8_t)(255 * (double)y / bmp->h_info.height);
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp->h_info.width; x++)
        {
            switch (x / (bmp->h_info.width / 3))
            {
                case 0:
                    red   = color_value;
                    green = 0;
                    blue  = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    red   = 0;
                    green = color_value;
                    blue  = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    red   = 0;
                    green = 0;
                    blue  = color_value;
                    break;
            }
            *p++ = blue;
            *p++ = green;
            *p++ = red;
            *p++ = 0XFF;
        }
    };
    return 0;
}

Bitmap* bmp_read(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* in = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (in == NULL) return NULL;
    // any size is ok
    Bitmap* one = bmp_create(800, 600);
    if (one == NULL)
    {
        fclose(in);
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t size =
        sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) + sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader);
    size_t res = fread((void*)one, (size_t)(1), size, in);
    if (res != size) return NULL;
    // read ok: now adjust the pixels and H W to the actual
    // values of this file
    size = one->h_info.height * one->h_info.width *
           4;  // 32bpp
    uint8_t* area = (uint8_t*)malloc(size);
    if (area == NULL)
    {
        fclose(in);
        return (NULL);
    };
    free(one->pixel);
    one->pixel = area;
    res = fread((void*)one->pixel, (size_t)(1), size, in);
    return one;
}

int bmp_setPixel(Bitmap* bmp,
    int x, int y, uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue)
{
    if (bmp == NULL) return -1;
    uint8_t* pPixel = bmp->pixel;
    // get address of coordinates of x,y
    pPixel += (y * 4) * bmp->h_info.width + (x * 4);
    pPixel[0] = blue;
    pPixel[1] = green;
    pPixel[2] = red;
    pPixel[3] = 0xFF;
    return 0;
}

int bmp_write(Bitmap* bmp, const char* filename)
{
    FILE* out = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (out == NULL) return -1;
    size_t res = 0;
    res        = fwrite(
        &bmp->h_bmp, (size_t)1, sizeof(BitmapFileHeader),
        out);
    res = fwrite(
        &bmp->h_info, (size_t)1, sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader),
        out);
    size_t size =
        (bmp->h_info.width * bmp->h_info.height * 4);
    res = fwrite(
        (const void*)bmp->pixel, (size_t)(1), size, out);
    if ( size != res )
    { 
        fclose(out);
        fprintf(stderr, "\tbmp_write() write %zd. %zd expected\n",res, size);
        fclose(out);
        return -2;    }
    res = fclose(out);
    return 0;
}

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Note: do not forget to align the structs to a word boundary for reading and writing the bitmap data. It is just a set using `#pragma` or similar in your compiler

#### output for this example

```
        bitmap created ok!
        bmp_fill returned 0
        bmp_write() returned 0
        bmp_fill() returned 0
        bmp_write() returned 0
        bmp_fill() returned 0
        bmp_write() returned 0
        bmp_read() read a [1024 x 768], size is 3145782
        bmp_write() returned 0
        bmp_grad() returned 0
        bmp_write() returned 0
        bmp_write() returned 0
        bitmap destroyed
        bitmap destroyed
        [end of tests]
```

And a few bitmaps will be written to disk.

#### Why is possibly easier this way?

As an example, `bmp_write()` code

```
int bmp_write(Bitmap* bmp, const char* filename)
{
    FILE* out = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (out == NULL) return -1;
    size_t res = 0;
    res        = fwrite(
        &bmp->h_bmp, (size_t)1, sizeof(BitmapFileHeader),
        out);
    res = fwrite(
        &bmp->h_info, (size_t)1, sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader),
        out);
    size_t size = (bmp->h_info.width * bmp->h_info.height * 4);
    res = fwrite(
        (const void*)bmp->pixel, size,
        (size_t)(1), out);
    res = fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Encapsulating the bitmap makes things easier to write, to test and to read.

#### `bmp_setPixel` as (another) example

```
int bmp_setPixel(Bitmap* bmp,
    int x, int y, uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue)
{
    if (bmp == NULL) return -1;
    uint8_t* pPixel = bmp->pixel;
    // get address of coordinates of x,y
    pPixel += (y * 4) * bmp->h_info.width + (x * 4);
    pPixel[0] = blue;
    pPixel[1] = green;
    pPixel[2] = red;
    pPixel[3] = 0xFF;
    return 0;
}
```

Writing this way makes it easy to build drawing primitives on the bitmap. Key to understand this is to see that

```
        pPixel += (y * 4) * bmp->h_info.width + (x * 4);
```

translates a `(x,y)` bitmap coordinate into a pixel address in the `struct`